# How to call foo() function from class A

Tags: class, oop, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'A'

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B'

class C(B):
    pass

c = C()
c.foo()
>>> B
```

I want to call the foo() method of class A. So how can I call this foo() method so that it will print 'A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you could define `C` like this:

```
class C(B):
    def foo(self):
        A.foo(self)
```

**However**, a better question might be: why are you trying to do this? A class needing to access functions from the, erm, "grandparent" that were also defined in the parent class is a pretty good sign that your inheritance model is not ideal. For example: does `C` need *anything* from `B`; could it inherit directly from `A`?

Comment: Thank you, This was the question asked in interview for me and I also became confused why would somebody try this.